# What are abstract classes and abstract methods?

Tags: java, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Abstract class in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320745/abstract-class-in-java)

I got several explanations but so far I'm not able to understand that what are the abstract classes and methods in Java.

Some said it has to do something with the security of the program, other said it isn't anything like that.

Even from the Dietel & Dietel's book I don't get it's purpose. 
When,where and why do we use it?

Kindly explain it like you're teaching a beginner, I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you read this ? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

Comment: All I got is that they can't be instantiated, I don't understand their complete purpose. Why do we need it when we already have access specifiers.

Comment: Abstract class helps designers to force developers to implements required mthods.

Comment: https://youtu.be/n9z_jWx2FNg

Answer (score 76, accepted):

An abstract class is a class that can't be instantiated. It's only purpose is for other classes to extend.

Abstract methods are methods in the abstract class (have to be declared abstract) which means the extending concrete class must override them as they have no body.

The main purpose of an abstract class is if you have common code to use in sub classes but the abstract class should not have instances of its own.

You can read more about it here: [Abstract Methods and Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)

Comment: extending concrete class must override abstract method.

Comment: In Java terminology an abstract method can override another  abstract method.  The key thing is to provide an implementation for all abstract methods.

Answer (score 78):

**-** `Abstract class` is one which **can't be instantiated**, i.e. **its** `object` **cannot be created.**

**-** `Abstract method` are **method's declaration without its definition**.

**-** A `Non-abstract class` can **only have Non-abstract methods.**

**-** An `Abstract class` can **have both the Non-abstract as well as Abstract methods.**

**- If** the `Class` has an `Abstract method` **then the class must also be Abstract.**

**-** An `Abstract method` **must be implemented by the very first Non-Abstract sub-class.**

**-** `Abstract class` in `Design patterns` are used to **encapsulate the behaviors that keeps changing.**

Comment: This is a really useful answer.

Comment: https://youtu.be/n9z_jWx2FNg

Answer (score 16):

An abstract method is a method signature declaration with no body. For instance:

```
public abstract class Shape {
    . . .

    public abstract double getArea();
    public abstract double getPerimeter();
}
```

The methods `getArea()` and `getPerimeter()` are abstract. Because the `Shape` class has an abstract method, it *must* be declared `abstract` as well. A class may also be declared `abstract` without any abstract methods. When a class is abstract, an instance of it cannot be created; one can only create instances of (concrete) subclasses. A concrete class is a class that is not declared abstract (and therefore has no abstract methods and implements all inherited abstract methods). For instance:

```
public class Circle extends Shape {
    public double radius;
    . . .

    public double getArea() {
        return Math.PI * radius * radius;
    }

    public double getPerimeter() {
        return 2.0 * Math.PI * radius;
    }
}
```

There are many reasons to do this. One would be to write a method that would be the same for all shapes but that depends on shape-specific behavior that is unknown at the `Shape` level. For instance, one could write the method:

```
public abstract class Shape {
    . . .

    public void printArea(PrintStream out) {
        out.println("The area is " + getArea());
    }
}
```

Admittedly, this is a contrived example, but it shows the basic idea: define concrete behavior in terms of unspecified behavior.

Another reason for having an abstract class is so you can partially implement an interface. All methods declared in an interface are inherited as abstract methods by any class that implements the interface. Sometimes you want to provide a partial implementation of an interface in a class and leave the details to subclasses; the partial implementation must be declared abstract.

Comment: Regardless, the example made it very clear for me.

Answer (score 3):

**abstract method** do not have body.A well defined method can't be declared abstract.

A **class** which **has abstract method** must be **declared as abstract**.

**Abstract class can't be instantiated.**

Answer (score 1):

An abstract class is a class that you can't create an object from, so it is mostly used for inheriting from.(I am not sure if you can have static methods in it)

An abstract method is a method that the child class must override, it does not have a body, is marked abstract and only abstract classes can have those methods.

Answer (score 0):

With abstract classes you can have some kind of skeleton for other classes to extend.

You can't instantiate them but you can put some common implementation which you can use in the classes that extend them.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get what abstract means in Java, you would ask: why they put this in ? Java may work without abstract stuff, BUT it makes part of a certain OO style or vocabulary. There exists really situations where an abstract class or method is an elegant way to express the program authors intention. Most when you are programming a framework or a library that will be used by others.

Answer (score -2):

[ABSTRACT CLASSES AND ABSTARCT METHODS FULL DESCRIPTION GO THROUGH IT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)

abstract method do not have body.A well defined method can't be declared abstract.

A class which has abstract method must be declared as abstract.

Abstract class can't be instantiated.