# Java must implement the inherited method?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have to extend the class geometric object to class triangle.

I cannot seem to find the error which causes the compiler to say

"must implement the inherited method GeometricObject.getArea"
"must implement the inherited method GeometricObject.getPerimeter"

Here is my code for triangle

```
public class Triangle extends GeometricObject {



double side1 = 1.0;
double side2 = 1.0;
double side3 = 1.0;

    public Triangle()
    {

    }

    public Triangle(double s1, double s2, double s3)
    {
        double side1 = s1;
        double side2 = s2;
        double side3 = s3;
    }

    public void getSide1()
    {
        System.out.print(side1);
    }

    public void getSide2()
    {
        System.out.print(side2);
    }

    public void getSide3()
    {
        System.out.print(side3);
    }


    public double getArea(double s1, double s2, double s3)
    {
        double s = (s1+s2+s3);
        double area = Math.sqrt((s-s1)-(s-s2)-(s-s3));
        return area;

    }

    public double getPerimeter(double s1, double s2, double s3)
    {
        double peri = (s1+s2+s3);
        return peri;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return ("Triangle Side 1: " + side1 + " Triangle Side 2: " + side2 + " Triangle Side 3: " + side3);
    }
```

}

Here is the code for geometricobject

```
    public abstract class GeometricObject { 
  private String color = "white"; 
  private boolean filled; 
  private java.util.Date dateCreated;

  /** Construct a default geometric object */ 
  protected GeometricObject() { 
          dateCreated = new java.util.Date(); 
        } 

 /** Construct a geometric object with color and filled value */ 
   protected GeometricObject(String color, boolean filled) { 
        dateCreated = new java.util.Date(); 
        this.color = color; this.filled = filled; 
        }

 /** Return color */ 
    public String getColor() {
         return color; 
     } 

  /** Set a new color */ 
     public void setColor(String color) { 
        this.color = color; } 
     /** Return filled. Since filled is boolean, the get method is named isFilled */ public boolean isFilled() {
           return filled;
           }

        /** Set a new filled */ 
        public void setFilled(boolean filled) { 
             this.filled = filled; 
           } 

        /** Get dateCreated */ 
         public java.util.Date getDateCreated() { 
             return dateCreated; 
           } 

        /** Return a string representation of this object */ 
         public String toString() {
            return "created on " + dateCreated + "\ncolor: " + color + " and filled: " + filled; }

        /** Abstract method getArea and getPerimete */
           public abstract double getArea();    //abstract method
           public abstract double getPerimeter();
        }
```

Can someone point out what did I miss?

Comment: You need to add a `getPerimeter()` method that doesn't have any parameters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are abstract classes and abstract methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13824142/what-are-abstract-classes-and-abstract-methods)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two methods in the parent class:

```
public abstract double getArea();
public abstract double getPerimeter();
```

...are marked `abstract`. That means that a subclass must either 1) Implement them, or 2) Declare itself `abstract` (`abstract class Triangle extends GeometricObject`).

Note that neither of them declares any parameters. The `getArea` and `getPerimeter` you have in `Triangle` take parameters (three doubles), and so they don't provide an implementation of the two methods above, which don't.

To be non-abstract, `Triangle` must have:

```
@Override
public double getArea() {
    // ...implementation...
}
@Override
public double getPerimeter() {
    // ...implementation...
}
```

Note that those, unlike the ones you currently have, don't accept any parameters.

There's no need for parameters on your methods; instead, use your instance fields `side1`, `side2`, and `side3`:

```
@Override
public double getArea()
{
    double s = this.side1 + this.side2 + this.side3;
    double area = Math.sqrt((s - this.side1) - (s - this.side2) - (s - this.side3));
    return area;
}

@Override
public double getPerimeter()
{
    double peri = this.side1 + this.side2 + this.side3;
    return peri;
}
```

Comment: how do you "implement" an abstract method from superclass?

Comment: @Yellow_13: You create methods with matching signatures in your subclass.

Comment: @Jaroslaw: How did *that* get in there? :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your child class, you have not overridden the abstract methods called getArea() and getParimeter() from GeometricObject class. You have simply overloaded them ( getArea() and getPermission()  methods )  in the child class, for instance check the prototypes of the corresponding methods in the two classes as they are not identical.
    Define getArea() [and getparimeter() ] method as follows (in the child class) :

```
public double getArea(){
  // your code goes here... 

  }
```

OR again declare them abstract as follows:

```
   public abstract double getArea();
```

but then you will have to make your child class abstract which will cost you that you won't be able to create   it's ( child class'  ) object.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getArea()` method is abstract. Thus, it should be have a definition somewhere. This is because when you declare a method as abstract, you cannot have a body for it, in the class in which it is declared. Hence, in the sub-class you need to provide that.

Abstract methods are more to ensure that all the sub-classes are following the same signature for that method, even though each sub- class' definition for that may be different.

So alter your arguments so that the signatures match.

**So where you have declared getArea() as abstract, add the 3 double arguments that you need, in the signature.**

i.e. Your declaration should be:

`public abstract double getArea(double s1,double s2,double s3);`

Answer (score 0):

You don't *override* but rather *overload* `getArea` and `getPerimeter` - Overriding means implementing the method according to the specifications of the super class, Overloading means extending a method with parameters but keeping the name and return type the same as the overloaded method.

Answer (score 0):

or you need to add parameters to your abstract methods in the abstract class:

```
public abstract double getArea(double side1, double side2, double side3);

    //abstract method
public abstract double getPerimeter(double side1, double side2, double side3);
```