# Instantiate error when I change class to abstract

Tags: java, instantiation

I'm working on my intro to programming assignment. Previously I created a program that models an employee using classes for Address Name and Date. This week the assignment is adding subclasses for Hourly and Salaried employees. To start with I tried making my employee class abstract, but when I do that, I get an error in my ArrayList "Cannot instantiate the type Employee (I put in a comment that shows where this error is)" I have posted my code below-- If anyone could give me any suggestions I would really appreciate it I've been struggling with what to do for hours.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public abstract class Employee
{
    private int id;
    private Name name;
    private Address address;
    private Date date;

    Employee (int id, Name name, Address address, Date date) 
    {
        setId(id);
        setName(name);
        setAddress(address);
        setDate(date);
    }

    //Setter
    public void setId(int id) 
    { 
        this.id = id; 
    }
    public void setName(Name name) 
    { 
        this.name = name; 
    }
    public void setAddress(Address address) 
    { 
        this.address = address; 
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) 
    { 
        this.date = date; 
    }

    //Getter
    public int getId() 
    { 
        return id; 
    }
    public Name getName() 
    { 
        return name; 
    }
    public Address getAddress() 
    { 
        return address; 
    }
    public Date getDate() 
    { 
        return date; 
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ID: " +getId()+ "Name: " +getName()+ "Address: " +getAddress()+ "Hire Date: "+ getDate();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Ask user for number of employees; create array of appropriate size
        System.out.println("Enter the number of employees: ");
        int numEmployees = input.nextInt();


        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

        // Read information on individual employees. 
        for (int i = 0; i < numEmployees; i++) 
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the employee ID number: " );
            int id = input.nextInt();

            input.nextLine(); //without this the scanner skips

            System.out.println("Enter the first name of the employee: " );
            String firstName = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter the last name of the employee: " );
            String lastName = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter the street address of the employee: " );
            String street = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter the city where the employee resides: " );
            String city = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter the state where the employee resides (two letter abbreviation): " );
            String state = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter the zip code of the employee: " );
            String zip = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter the month the employee was hired (1-12): " );
            int month = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Enter the day the employee was hired (1-31): " );
            int day = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Enter the year the employee was hired (1900-2020): " );
            int year = input.nextInt();

            input.nextLine(); //without this the scanner skips to last name

            Name name = new Name(firstName, lastName);
            Address address = new Address(street, city, state, zip);
            Date date = new Date(month, day, year);   

            //this is where I get the error
            Employee employee = new Employee(id, name, address, date);

            employees.add(employee);
        }

        /**
         * Print out information on all the employees 
         * Use Foreach loop to iterate through ArrayList
         **/
        for(Employee employee : employees) 
        {
            System.out.print("ID:" + employee.getId() + " ");
            System.out.print("Name:" + employee.getName().getFirstName() + " ");
            System.out.println(employee.getName().getLastName());
            System.out.print("Address:" + employee.getAddress().getStreet() + " ");
            System.out.print(employee.getAddress().getCity() + " ");
            System.out.print(employee.getAddress().getState() + " ");
            System.out.println(employee.getAddress().getZip());
            System.out.print("Hire Date: " + employee.getDate().getMonth() + "/");
            System.out.print(employee.getDate().getDay() + "/");
            System.out.println(employee.getDate().getYear());
            System.out.println();
        }
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't instantiate abstract type (that is kind of purpose of making it abstract). If you need to instantiate it don't make it abstract.

Comment: an abstract class cannot be instantiated

Comment: Abstract classes does not need initialized constructor, you should have empty constructor.

Comment: @kaanyılmaz that isn't true at all. An abstract class should have a constructor to appropriately initialize its member variables.

Comment: Oh sorru for wrong information then.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot instantiate abstract classes in Java. You can, however, instantiate a quick non-abstract subclass from them. In this subclass you'd of course need to implement all methods that are abstract as well

```
abstract class Foo {
 ...
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
  Foo foo = new Foo(); //Can't do
  Foo foo = new Foo() {}; // this will work, as long as Foo has a null constructor; if Foo has abstract methods, make sure to define them concretely within the { ... } block
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Usually abstract classes are used to provide the basic data/methods to subclasses.
You cannot instantiate an object of abstract class.*
It's just a level of program abstraction and a good practice to create a hierarchical class structure.

*But you may use a reference to abstract class for creating an object of a concrete type.

```
AbstractClass obj = new ConcreteClass(); // if ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I think in that case I should separate out an abstract employee class, and put the main method/asking for user input in a different class.

Comment: @H.P., yes, and throw away `abstract` word from `Employee` if you don't have specific classes as `Manager` or `Programmer` for example

Answer (score 0):

Making a class abstract usually means that it will be used as a parent class for subclasses that need to implement the same methods. *Abstract classes cannot be instantiated.* Once you have created your required subclasses, `HourlyEmployee` and `SalariedEmployee`, you'll be able to define a new object like this:
    `Employee employee = new HourlyEmployee();`
or 
    `Employee employee = new SalariedEmployee();`
Here's a great explanation regarding abstract classes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1320887/6062407

Comment: Thank you, that article was very helpful. I wrote up my subclasses HourlyEmployee and SalariedEmployee but I'm not sure how to incorporate them into my ArrayList for user input. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You just have to create a constructor (for each subclass) with the same parameters as the constructor of your parent class, then invoke `super(id, name, address, date);`. After that you can replace your code in the `for loop` to `Employee employee = new HourlyEmployee(id, name, address, date);` or `Employee employee = new SalariedEmployee(id, name, address, date);`, depending on your needs. You probably have to do some checking (maybe an input and `if statement`?) before instantiation to tell which sub class object you need to create.