# how to create a object of abstract class without implementing method

Tags: java, abstract-class

In my  Graph class i extends a abstract class List(That extends comparable). I want to make object of list but don't want to implement (abstract)method in graph class.Whoever extends Graph must implement  that method. How i can do this?

graph

```
public abstract class Graph<T> extends List<T>{

private  List<List<T>> adjacencyList;
private  int vertexNumber;
private boolean directed;


public Graph(int vertex,boolean directed)
{
    vertexNumber=vertex;
    this.directed=directed;
    adjacencyList= new List<List<T>>()// The problem is here compiler wants the implementation of the abstract method.
    createVertex(vertexNumber);

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Abstract class in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320745/abstract-class-in-java)

Comment: You can't, by definition of what an abstract class is.

Comment: You can't extend List<T> because List is not a generic, and cannot be parameterized.;

Comment: @FredK You **can** extend List<T> , List **is** generic and **can** be parameterized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this to force subclasses to provide a means to create the list:

```
public abstract class Graph<T> {
   private List<List<T>> x;

   public Graph(int vertex,boolean directed) {
      adjacencyList = createListOfList();
   }

   protected abstract List<List<T>> createListOfList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are defining an abstract class extending a List
so basically you have no more than 2 options;

1. either implement the methods of the list
2. or defined abstract to and the class that inherits the Graph will have to handle it...

Answer (score 0):

You can not create an instance of an abstract class, you must implement all methods.

However in your situation you just need to provide one of the existing implementations. Most likely an `ArrayList`

```
adjacencyList = new ArrayList<List<T>>();
```

If you look at the [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) there are several implementing classes listed.

Most common are:
- [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)
- [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)
- [Stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html)

**Design Question:** Why does your Graph extend List and then have a List of Lists? Typically you only do one of the following

- Extend List, in this case your Graph **is a** list
- List field, in this case your Graph **has a** list

It is confusing to have both relationships on one object.

Answer (score 0):

since you have provide PRIVATE access modifier in :

```
private  List<List<T>> adjacencyList;
private  int vertexNumber;
private boolean directed;
```

so, even if you another class (suppose) A extends Graph, it would be able to access those variables.  Try with public access specifier, it may help.

THANK YOU