# What is an AbstractActivity in android?

Tags: android

What is an Abstract Activity in android? This question was asked at one of the interview. I tried searching about this at androidxref unfortunately not able to found.

Can any one help to answer this , Thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Abstract class in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320745/abstract-class-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

There is no such term in Android system called `AbstractActivity`.

Abstract activity is any activity which has been marked as abstract. 
And like any other abstract java class, it cannot be instantiated and hence it will fail if passed as intent to `startActivity()` method. Also Android Studio will not allow you to declare such activity in the manifest file.

These abstract activities are mostly used by some android libraries to declare abstract methods and provides any method implementations useful for its task like login mechanism.

One of the advantage of this approach over an interface is that it can make use of activity callback methods.

Answer (score 3):

As in comments the purpose of `AbstractActivity` is same as abstract class in java, which cannot be used directly(direct instance creation is not possible).
Using abstract activity you can define a group functionality for app activity screens.

For example,

**LoginScreen**: Abstract activity holding some functions defined
**UserLoginScreen**: specific ui/function for common user
**AdminLoginScreen**: specific ui/function for admin user