# Can static and abstract keyword used together in java?

Tags: java, inner-classes

As I know that static and final combination can be used together but static and abstract or final and abstract combination is not allowed in java. But some where I have seen code like below

```
public class Enclosing {

    private static int x = 1;

    public static abstract class StaticNested {

        public abstract void run();
    }
  }
```

Can someone please explain the the concept and practical uses of this scenario.

Comment: Do you understand [what it means for a nested class to be static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class)? Do you understand [what it means for a class to be abstract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320745/abstract-class-in-java)? If you understand both those things then you'll understand the concept of an abstract static nested class.

Comment: Short answer: No. Longer answer: No, because it would not be useful.

Comment: @Bohemian Static nested _classes_ certainly can be abstract and have the same valid uses as top-level abstract classes. That said, static _methods_ cannot be abstract, but the OP used a class as an example and not a method.

Comment: @Slaw Hmmm. Quite so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static` and `abstract` can be used together for *nested classes*, eg

```
class A {
    static abstract class B {
        abstract void someMethod();
    }
}
```

`B` is a `static` *nested* class that requires concrete subclasses to implement `someMethod()`.

but cannot be used together for *methods*, eg

```
static abstract void someMethod();  // compile error
```

Of course `abstract` and `final` can't be used together - such a combination would be nonsensical.

#### Uses of `static abstract class`

A suitable use of a `static abstract class` would be for node-like objects that only your class uses, for example a class the represent an entry in a map (eg `java.util.Map.Entry` which is an `interface`, but could have been a static abstract class), or a class for a node of a `LinkedList`, but one where the implementation is left to implementatioons of the enclosing class that themselves also use and provide implementations of the nested class by extending it too.