# Issue with childeventlistener in Firebase

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having issues with the below code

```java
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
private ChildEventListener mChildListener;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("MyItem");
    mChildListener = new ChildEventListener(); 
    mDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(mChildListener);
}
```

The error is childeventlistener is abstract cannot be instantised for the below line
mChildListner = new ChildEventListener()

Any idea what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: the error is very clear , you can't create the object of an abstract  class, do you know what an abstract class is?

Comment: Sorry but i'm a newbie in programming(still no excuse) but i did read up on it before posting on here and was still confused with the error. I found that an abstract class is a method that is declared and may require subclasses.

Comment: video about abstract class https://youtu.be/3sDxmJVQhA0 don't mind his accent it is a very good explanation and here are many answers about abstract class https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320745/abstract-class-in-java in encourage to to understand java basics first before starting with firebase

Comment: Thanks. Will do that

Comment: although the `ChildEventListner` is not an abstract class it is an interface , but you will get the idea

Answer (score 1):

ChildEventListener is an interface you can't in java create an instance of that, instead you need to make a class that implements this interface.

instead of this:

```
mChildListener = new ChildEventListener(); 
mDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(mChildListener);
```

You do this:

........

```
 mChildListener = new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());


    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onChildChanged:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());


    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onChildRemoved:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());


    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onChildMoved:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());


    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "postComments:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());

    }
};


mDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(mChildListener);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for putting me in the right direction.

Comment: If that helped make sure to accept so others know what answer to look at.