# How to solve error ""cannot instantiate the type Triple""

Tags: java, instantiation, triples

I'm trying to use a triple to return multiple values but I get "cannot instantiate the type Triple" I tried multiple things but nothing worked. What is the correct Syntax?

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Triple;

private static Triple<String, String, String> test() {
    Triple<String, String, String> triple = new Triple<>();
    ...
    return triple;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Abstract class in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320745/abstract-class-in-java)

Comment: And if I don't want to create another class?

Comment: Then you find an existing implementation, or an alternative library (for instance, vavr.io also has Tuples)

Answer (score 5):

Triple is abstract, use MutableTriple or ImmutableTriple instead.

Comment: With ImmutableTriple I get "Cannot infer type arguments for ImmutableTriple<>"

Comment: Then you could explicitly specify the type parameters, like we did in the good old days of Java 6.

Comment: `ImmutableTriple` requires 3 values to be specified in the constructor.

Comment: `ImmutableTriple<String, String, String> triple = new ImmutableTriple<String, String, String>(a, b, c);` or `ImmutableTriple<String,String,String> triple = ImmutableTriple.of(a, b, c);`